# How can we pivot in this scenario in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, sql-query-store

I have this table:

```
+----------+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| personId | Name   | Age | height | weight |
+----------+--------+-----+--------+--------+
| 1        | Aritra | 20  | 5.6    | 56     |
| 1        | Aritra | 30  | 5.6    | 76     |
+----------+--------+-----+--------+--------+
```

But require the output to be like this:

```
+---------------+----------+--------------+----------+
| AttributeName | personId | Presentvalue | OldValue |
+---------------+----------+--------------+----------+
| Height        | 1        | 5.6          | 5.6      |
| weight        | 1        | 76           | 56       |
+---------------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

I tried to get this using pivot but am facing a problem. How can I do this, with or without using pivot?

Thank you.

Comment: please avoid image in question

Comment: give sample data to get good answers @aritra

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which **exact** problem are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

`union all` is probably the simplest method:

```
select 'Height' as attributeName, personId,
       (case when age = 30 then height end) as newValue,
       (case when age = 20 then height end) as oldValue
from t 
union all
select 'Weight' as attributeName, personId,
       (case when age = 30 then weight end) as newValue,
       (case when age = 20 then weight end) as oldValue;
```